# Linear combination of two vectors that zeroes out the quadratic form of matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a given $N\times N$ hermitian matrix. Let $v$ be a vector such that $v^HAv>0$ and $w$ be a vector such that $w^HAw<0$ ($w^H$ denotes conjugate transpose of $w$). Assume both $v$ and $w$ are unit-norm. Does there exist any non-zero vector $x$ which is a linear combination of $v$ and $w$, such that $x^HAx=0$?

Comment: $Q(v)=v^HAv$ is a continuous function of $v$.

Comment: So is the argument that since Q(.) is continuous, for a given $v$ and $w$, there should exist a linear combination of $v$ and $w$ which gives the zero crossing?

Comment: can you give a constructive argument?

Comment: I’ll have to think about it a bit for a constructive proof. I expect that it’ll involve expanding $Q(a\mathbf v+b\mathbf w)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

A non-constructive proof:

Let $Q(\mathbf u)=\mathbf u^HA\mathbf u$. Since $Q(k\mathbf u)=\left|k\right|^2Q(\mathbf u)$, we know that $\mathbf w$ is not a scalar multiple of $\mathbf v$. Consider a parametrization $\mathbf c(t)$ ($t\in\mathbb R$) of the unit circle in the plane spanned by $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf w$ with $\mathbf c(a)=\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf c(b)=\mathbf w$. $Q(\mathbf c(t))$ is a continuous function of $t$, so there must be some $t_0\in(a,b)$ for which $Q(\mathbf c(t_0))=0$.

Answer (score 1):

A constructive proof:

Let $v^HAv = P\ \ and\ \  w^HAw = -M \tag 1$

Let $z = v + ew$  where $e \in \mathbb{C}$

Solve for $z$ s.t. $z^HAz = 0$

$[v + ew]^HA[v + ew] = 0$

Use Einstein notation (summation over common indecies):

$(\overline{v_r} + \overline{e}\overline{w_r})A_{rc}(v_c + ew_c) = 0$

$A_{rc}\overline{v_r}v_c + A_{rc}\overline{w_r}w_ce\overline{e} + A_{rc}\overline{v_r}w_ce + A_{rc}v_c\overline{w_r}\overline{e} = 0$

$P -Me\overline{e} + A_{rc}\overline{v_r}w_ce + \left(\overline{\overline{A_{rc}}\overline{v_c}w_r}\right)\overline{e} = 0$

Since $A^H = A$ then $\overline{A_{rc}} = A_{cr}$

$P -Me\overline{e} + A_{rc}\overline{v_r}w_ce + \left(\overline {A_{cr}\overline{v_c}w_r}\right)\overline{e} = 0$

Let $x + iy = A_{rc}\overline{v_r}w_c \tag 2$

Note that $A_{cr}\overline{v_c}w_r = A_{rc}\overline{v_r}w_c$

$P -Me\overline{e} + (x+iy)e + \left(\overline {x+iy}\right)\overline{e} = 0$

$P -Me\overline{e} + (x+iy)e + \left(x-iy\right)\overline{e} = 0$

$P -Me\overline{e} + x(e+\overline{e}) + iy(e-\overline{e}) = 0$

---

Let $e \in \mathbb{R}$ The linear combination in $\mathbb{R}$.

$P -Me^2 + 2xe  = 0$

$Me^2 - 2xe - P = 0$

$e = \frac{2x \pm \sqrt{4x^2 + 4PM}}{2M}$

$e = \frac{x \pm \sqrt{x^2 + PM}}{M} \tag 3$

$z = v + ew \tag 4$

---

What if we let $e \in \mathbb{C}$ s.t. $e = e_R + ie_I$

$P -Me\overline{e} + x(e+\overline{e}) + iy(e-\overline{e}) = 0$

$P -M(e_{R}^2+e_{I}^2) + 2xe_R - 2ye_{I} = 0$

$e_{R}^2 - \frac{2xe_R}{M}  + e_{I}^2 + \frac{2ye_{I}}{M} = \frac{P}{M}$

$(e_{R} - \frac{x}{M})^2  + (e_{I} + \frac{y}{M})^2 = \frac{P}{M} + (\frac{x}{M})^2 + (\frac{y}{M})^2 \tag 5$

$e$ is a circle in the complex plane.

---

Let $z_2 = cz$ where $c \in \mathbb{C}$

Then $z_{2}^HAz_2 = \overline{c}z^HAzc = |c|^2z^HAz = 0$

A solution $z$ can be scaled and rotated to produce another solution.

---

A more general solution of $z = av + bw$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ would be interesting.

$z = av + bw = a(v+\frac{b}{a}w)$ which is equivalent to $z = v + ew$ and the scale and rotation argument.

Answer (score -1):

A constructive proof:

$\exists \lambda = -\frac{v^HAv}{w^HAw} \in \mathbb{R}^*_+$ such as $v^HAv+\lambda w^HAw = 0$.

if $w^H Av =0$ then we can construct $u=v+\lambda^{1/2}w$ which verify:

$u^HAu=v^HAv+\lambda w^HAw + \lambda^{1/2}(w^H Av+v^H Aw)=0$

else let $\tilde w = i(w^HAv) w$ then $ \tilde w^H A \tilde w  = (-i)(i)|w^H Av|^2 w^H Aw < 0$

so there exists $v$ and $\tilde w$ and $\tilde \lambda= -\frac{v^HAv}{\tilde w^HA\tilde w}  \in \mathbb{R}^*_+$ such as $v^HAv+\lambda \tilde w^HA\tilde w =0$ in one hand.

In other hand  $\tilde w^HAv = (-i) (\overline{w^HAv}) (w^HAv) =- \overline{\tilde w^HAv}$.

So $(v+{\lambda}^{1/2}\tilde w)^HA(v+{\lambda}^{1/2}\tilde w) = v^HAv+\tilde \lambda \tilde w^HA\tilde w + \tilde \lambda^{1/2}(\tilde w^HAv + \overline{\tilde w^HAv}) = 0$

Comment: How does $v^HAv+\lambda\tilde w^HA\tilde w=0$ in the case that $\tilde w^HA\tilde w=0$, i.e., when $w^HAv=0$?

Comment: You're right to ask the question. In this case we do not need to construct $\tilde w$. $w$ is ok I think. Do you want me to modify the answer?

Comment: Please do. The proof is incomplete.